# TSQL Completing dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, dataset

I'm new here and have a question. thanks for any help you can give.

I have a dataset that is incomplete and want to make it complete based on values in a second set.

How do I go about doing that using MSSQL 2014?

This is code to generate the example datasets:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ( K1 INT , K2 INT, K3 INT )
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ( K4 INT )

INSERT INTO @T1 (k1,k2,k3) VALUES 
  (3,   226,    5),(3,  226,    10
),(3,   226,    15),(3, 226,    20
),(3,   312,    5),(3,  312,    10
),(3,   312,    30),(4, 280,    20
),(4,   280,    25),(4, 280,    50
),(4,   280,    55)

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (0),(5),(10),(15),(20),(25),(30),(35),(40),(45),(50),(55)

SELECT * FROM @T1
SELECT * FROM @T2
```

How do I get to this result?

```
3   226 5
3   226 10
3   226 15
3   226 20
3   226 25
3   226 30
3   226 35
3   226 40
3   226 45
3   226 50
3   226 55
3   312 5
3   312 10
3   312 15
3   312 20
3   312 25
3   312 30
3   312 35
3   312 40
3   312 45
3   312 50
3   312 55
4   280 0
4   280 5
4   280 10
4   280 15
4   280 20
4   280 25
4   280 30
4   280 35
4   280 40
4   280 45
4   280 50
4   280 55
```

e.g. for every key (t1.k1,t1.k2) add the missing rows (in t2.k4 and not in t1.k3) supplying the correct values from t1.k1,t1.k2

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show us the code for you're best attempt at achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

If your second dataset is guaranteed to be complete and your first k1 and k2 columns are guaranteed to be the same for each row in k4, you can disregard what is in k3 entirely:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ( K1 INT , K2 INT, K3 INT )
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ( K4 INT )

INSERT INTO @T1 (k1,k2,k3) VALUES 
  (3,   226,    5),(3,  226,    10
),(3,   226,    15),(3, 226,    20
),(3,   312,    5),(3,  312,    10
),(3,   312,    30),(4, 280,    20
),(4,   280,    25),(4, 280,    50
),(4,   280,    55)

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (0),(5),(10),(15),(20),(25),(30),(35),(40),(45),(50),(55)

SELECT *
FROM (select distinct k1, k2 from @T1) T1
    cross join @T2
order by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT K1, K2, K4 FROM @T2 T2 cross JOIN @T1 T1 
ORDER BY K1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do ths using a cross join:

```
select t1.k1, t1.k2, t2.k4
from (select distinct k1, k2 from @t1) t1 cross join
     @t2 t2;
```